# How to convert RPM package to a format meaningful to Ubuntu

Tags: deb, conversion, rpm, alien

I'm using a special program that has only .rpm version available as installer. As I need to run it on Ubuntu, Is there a way to install it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which program is it? You can always try and convert it using `alien` in command line.

With alien you can convert from/to rpm/deb/tgz/slp.

The process is pretty straightforward:

```
sudo alien myfile.rpm
```

I think it will also attempt to install it.

If you don't have Alien installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

Comment: WOW, that works great! But i have another questions...(sorry i'm new to Ubuntu..)

I got the .edb file but how to install? Could you let me know the command? thanks a lot!

Comment: if alien hasn't installed it already, try `sudo dpkg -i myfile.deb`